# Why can importing a file let some parts of that file be accessed but not things which aren't exported?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, module

I was following a React tutorial where a javascript file A containing some functions and various console log statements etc is imported into another javascript file B.

One of those functions from file A is then called in file B but there was an error, yet all the console log statements and other commands from file A executed fine.

I wondered why some parts of the file A ran ok but not the functions, doesn't importing the whole file essentially bring everything in that file into scope for file B?

For instance:

a.js

```
console.log("hi");

function test1() {
  console.log("test1");
}
```

b.js

```
import './a.js';

test1();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...doesn't importing the whole file essentially bring everything in that file into scope for file B?

No, not at all. The example module you've shown doesn't export anything, so everything inside it (the `test1` function) is entirely private to the module. This is one of the key benefits of modules: They provide private scope for module details that you don't want to share, with an explicit way to share the things you do want to share.

> I wondered why some parts of the file A ran ok but not the functions...

That's because you've imported the module. Even if the module doesn't import or export anything, its top-level code is still run as part of the process of loading it (the first time it's imported). Some modules are designed purely to be loaded for their side-effects (what their top-level code does). Your example is like that; its side effect is the `console.log` it does.

Comment: FWIW, I cover modules in detail in Chapter 13 of my recent book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. Links in my profile if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I should have clarified with an example but imagine if you had some console.log statements etc in a.js and then imported the whole file into b.js, then the console statements would run but if you tried to use the example2 function then you would get an error. I understand it's not exported but as you import the whole file doesn't that bring it's contents into scope?

Comment: @jobe - I've updated the answer. :-)